# Get to Jobs Messages from Developer Story

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I recently discovered it was possible to receive (and reply to) messages to job recruiters through a [Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages) feature. The page looks like this.

[image]

I'd like to know if there is another way to access this tab (through Developer Story) rather than directly pasting the link, or looking for recruiter messages through your notifications tab and navigating there by clicking on the notification.

<sup>If you're wondering how I got there, it was after receiving messages through notifications that took me there. I've hidden the messages for their privacy, which is why you don't see anything on the page.</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'd like to know if there is another way to access this tab (through Developer Story) rather than directly pasting the link, or looking for recruiter messages through your notifications tab and navigating there by clicking on the notification.

**1.** The fastest way would be to **bookmark the link** in your web browser: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages

**2.** The fastest way **by nagivating from the SO homepage** would be two clicks:

[image]

**3.** Alternatively, as you have found out, you can also reach the messages page via a **new message notification** (also two clicks, but it links directly to the message IIRC).

**4.** Lastly, since Jobs shares the same inbox as the [network-wide inbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qcZ7.png), you will receive an **email notification** with a link to the message, if you have opted to receive one via email settings:

[image]